# How to call my named query in my view

Tags: java, java-ee-6

I'm struggling to figure out how to call my named query...

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Content.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Content c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Content.findById", query = "SELECT c FROM Content c WHERE c.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Content.findByUserId", query = "SELECT c FROM Content c WHERE c.userId = :userId")})
public class Content implements Serializable {
...
```

In my view, I've tried a few variations of this, but can't seem to pinpoint the correct usage.

```
<ol> <%
    List<Content> contentList = model.Content.findAll();
    if (contentList != null) {
        for (Content content : contentList) { %>
            <li> <%= content %> </li> <%
        }
    } %>
</ol>
```

On Google I keep finding results where people have usage like:

```
List results = em.createNamedQuery("findAll").getResultList();
```

Should I have a reference to `em` within my view, or is this referring to within a model?  I can't seem to find a solid example to help me see the full picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you've given looks like it belongs in the *Service Layer* of a [Three-Tier Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Three-tier_architecture).

That is, you will have a `ContentService` which exposes methods like `findAll()`. Then your `ContentController` will call this method at the appropriate time, and place the resulting `List<Content>` into the model, which the view can then (finally!) use.

Here's how I'd write your `ContentService` implementation (assuming a `ContentService` interface has already been defined):

```
public class ContentServiceImpl implements ContentService {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em; // Gets wired in by Spring

    public List<Content> findAllContent() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Content.findAll").getResultList();
    }

    ...
}
```

I know it seems like a lot of work when compared to what you've attempted (directly accessing a named query "on" an object, from the view), but it's a pretty major violation of [separation of concerns](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SeparationOfConcerns), which is the main idea behind the [MVC](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ModelViewController) pattern that everyone uses these days.

Think about what happens if you get told that `findAll` should *actually* only find `Content` objects with a new `visible` flag set `true`. With your current approach (if it even worked) you'd have to change your **view** - when the change should be isolated to a much lower layer.

Now think of what has to be done with the above implementation. Write a new `@NamedQuery` on your `Content` object, and then call *that* in the `findAllContent()` method. Nothing else changes.

Comment: The named queries exist on my models.  I'm also not using Spring.  Can you provide an example without Spring?  I'd actually like my controller to call the `findAll` and pass it to the view, but I'm not sure how to do that when I'm dispatching the request to a .jsp file

Answer (score 0):

You can use Application managed EntityManager if you don't want to use Spring. That is, just write POJO and create an EntityManager there like this:

```
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
private EntityManager em;

public List findAll(){
   em.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("your-persistence-unit-name");
   return results = em.createNamedQuery("findAll").
}
```